# How can get last value of form charge in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onchange, jqueryform

I am trying to make a form where a customer can choose parson and automatically show the cost depend on parson number. So for that, I used jQuery form change function and calculate the cost inside of the function. My all logic is working ok but the issue is when increasing number then showing multiple costs.

**Visual look:**

[image]

Always I want to show the last one/ updated one

**Blow my code:**

```
var adultsSingleChage = 200;
var childrenSingleCharge = 100;
var infantsSingleCharge = 50;


$('#absbt_form input').change(function(){
    var adults = $("#absbt_adults").val();
    var adultsCharge = adults * adultsSingleChage;

    var children = $("#absbt_children").val();
    var childrenCharge = children * childrenSingleCharge;

    var infants = $("#absbt_infants").val();
    var infantsCharge = infants * infantsSingleCharge;

    var totalCharge = adultsCharge + childrenCharge + infantsCharge;

    console.log(totalCharge);


    $('.total_cost').append(totalCharge);

});
```

I know I did the maximum of logic but for last logic, I'm confused.

**How can I just show the last one?**

Comment: `$('.total_cost').text(totalCharge);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`append` adds new content to existing one - that's the reason of having previous values.

Instead of using `append` use `text`:

```
$('.total_cost').text(totalCharge);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the code you are [appending](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which means you are adding the text into the element instead of replacing it. You can use the following two methods:

1. [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/): `$('.total_cost').text("iota")`
2. [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/): `$('.total_cost').html("iota")`

Note: Use id selector or with class use `$($('.total_cost')[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Use html(totalCharge) instead of append(totalCharge)

Comment: No need to use `html` here. It's just a plain text.

Comment: OP is adding text not any html entity.